# Retrieving the salary from the employee table query

Tags: sql, db2

I was going through this link http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-find-second-highest-or-maximum-salary-sql.html which shows to retrieve the second highest salary from Employee table, Referring to the table schema as shown in the example , Please advise how to find the 3rd highest or 4 Th highest salary from the employee table itself

Comment: @MahmoudGamal..DB2 brother..!

Answer (score 2):

There is an example there that explains that for MySQL, you can get the second highest via

```
SELECT salary FROM 
  (SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary LIMIT 1
```

If you replace `2` by `3`, you will get the 3rd highest. The subsequery selects the `n` highest salaries and the outer query then selects the lowest of that result.

This scheme can be used with any RDBMS, be it with slightly different syntax. For DB2, I think the following should work (but I cannot verify it at the moment):

```
SELECT salary FROM 
  (SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY) AS emp 
ORDER BY salary FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
  select * from employee
  order by salary desc
  limit 4) x
order by salary
limit 1;
```

You apply two limits: one for the inner query to get the top 4 rows, then another limit to get the lowest row from those.

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to use the `DENSE_RANK` OLAP function to define a rank, then select whichever ordered value you need.  For example, to find the third highest salary:

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM (
   SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rank
        , salary 
   FROM employee
   ) AS xxx
WHERE rank = 3
```

`DENSE_RANK` will take care of any "ties" in the data.  Since it's possible there might be more than one employee with the same salary, use the `MAX` function to keep only one.  The `limit 1` syntax might also work, but I've never used that.